# How to execute aliased command in a subshell

Tags: bash, scripting

I have an alias in my ~/.bashrc file

```
alias gw="some_command"
```

and I want to be able to execute `gw` in a subshell like this:

```
echo $(gw arg1 arg2 ...)
```

Is there a way to do this? Or a workaround of some sort? I've tried different things but nothing is working out so far.

Comment: In general, btw, consider using functions rather than aliases. Among other things, you can export a function into the environment, making it available for shells run as subprocesses (as opposed to subshells -- a subshell proper will have no problem with an alias if its parent acknowledged same).

Comment: ...which is to say that `echo $(gw arg1 arg2 ...)` will work if `gw arg1 arg2 ...` did, but if you're doing this in a script, that probably wasn't true either.

Comment: Think about the consequences of what you're asking for here. Lots of users have, say, `cp` aliased to `cp -i`. Do you really want scripts to need to deal with not just system defaults, but every possible set of personal customizations and tweaks?

Comment: `unalias gw; gw() { "some_command"; }; declare -xf gw` should work

Answer (score 2):

```
alias hw="echo hello "
echo "$(hw world)"
```

works just fine for me.

I think your problem is you're trying to do it in a script and scripts (=noninteractive bash)
don't support aliases unless you explicitly enable alias support in them.

In bash, you can enable alias support with:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: after running `shopt -s expand_aliases`, I still get the error "gw: command not found"

Comment: @Mark, ...you also need to have sourced `~/.bashrc` into your script -- it's only included in interactive shells by default.

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash? You must either run the script with `bash script_name` or with `./script_name` and then your first line in the script must be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Mark, ...which, frankly, is the case for good reason -- it would be damned hard to write scripts that worked reliably across multiple user accounts, much less multiple machines, if every script had to be able to cope with every user's possible set of personal customizations.